# Removing Controller from url in a specific scenario

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to remove `Controller` named `Home` from `url` when user clicks on `About` and `Contact` pages in `ASP.NET MVC sample application`. I tried this but it is giving me a 404 error.

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home" });
```

When i remove this all works perfectly.
**Note** I want to remove Controller name only when Controller is Home. Other Controller should remain same. 
Further I kept the code in `Route.Config` file above

```
 routes.MapRoute("Home", "{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home" });

 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Required Result**

> **abc.com/Home/About** should shown as **abc.com/About**
>   **abc.com/Home/Contact** should shown as **abc.com/Contact**

Comment: did you study at Seneca?

Comment: nope. never there @ayilmaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map new route in the global.asax (add it before the default one), for example:

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRouteforHomeController", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route  any defalt you want
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Comment: this is specific for Home/Index. I want it for Home/About and Home/Contact

Comment: Rex it is not working with any other controller except home and Account. What i want is it remove controller when controller name is website and pass all remaining controller and actions

Answer (score -2):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Default",
 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "DefaultControllerName", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

If u will specify the controller name then this will work with that controller name. Bu if not the by default it will take controller name as **DefaultControllerName**.