# URL rewriting issue through Route.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

I am able to do the URL rewriting of my MVC Application by using a `Route.Config` file as below:

```
    //Offline Consult Route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "WrittenStep2",
        url: "written/step2/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Offline", action = "Step2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Written",
        url: "written",
        defaults: new { controller = "Offline", action = "Index" }
        );
```

In the above code, I have Controller as "Offline" and have some actions.

I am able to change the route:

**TO:** www.abc.com/written

**FROM** www.abc.com/Offline

My problem is that I am still able to access the URL: www.abc.com/Offline. How can I resolve this issue?

I have tried to deny access of this URL to the users by using the `Begin_Request` method of `Global.asax` file.

But after doing that I won't be able to access my methods which I am calling using jQuery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Offline/HelloWorld",
    data: jsonString,
    contentType: "application/json",
    ...
```

Is there any way to restrict users from using the same URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337372/507025 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/18627655/507025

Comment: can you please read my question again??
I am trying to say that even after rewriting, i am able to access my old Urls.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.4sln.com/Articles/seo-friendly-url-rewriting-in-mvc-by-keeping-references-in-database), it might be helpful for you
...
for the given example, if you want to restrict or navigate users for a specific URL, you can try:

1- include a route for Offline with custom route handler

```
            routes.MapRoute(
              "OfflineWithoutParameterRoute",
              "Offline"
             ).RouteHandler = new NewUrlRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WrittenStep2",
            url: "written/step2/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Offline", action = "Step2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Written",
            url: "written",
            defaults: new { controller = "Offline", action = "Index" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

2- Create your MvcRouteHandler as

```
    public class NewUrlRouteHandler : System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //restrict or navigate to any destination
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "index";

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

which you can maintain any approach

so any hit for **www.abc.com/Offline** will hit to custom handler and any route for **www.abc.com/Offline/prm** will follow the default route.

I have tried with controller/action you given as an example and it should be helpful for you.

```
    public class OfflineController : Controller
{
    // GET: Offline
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Step2(int id)
    {

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult HelloWorld(int id)
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if given link solve the problem, what happens if link disappear? You should elaborate some.

Comment: should be detailed now.. hope it helps